# How to delete files from specific folders in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

So, I have a requirement to delete all files from specific folders within a directory. These are folders that end with "-outputs" in their names and I need to delete all files in those particular folders.

Is there a command in linux that lets you do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can execute the following command:

```
rm $YOUR_PATH\*-outputs
```

Change $YOUR_PATH to the path where the files are located.

If you want to ignore nonexistent files and arguments, and avoid the prompt, you can use the -f option.

```
rm -f $YOUR_PATH\*-outputs
```

You can see the different rm options here:
[rm Linual manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html)

Comment: I don't want to delete the folders themselves. Just the files inside those folders. This will delete the folders as well right?!

Comment: If you don't use the -r option, rm will only delete the files inside a directory. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714900/remove-only-files-in-directory-on-linux-not-directories