# How to exclude a folder tree from find command on an Android 10 phone

Tags: android, bash

I have this command that works to clear the cache files older than 3 days of all apps on my Android 10 phone:

```
find /data/data/*/cache -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -r {} +
```

Now I want to exclude the folder `/data/data/org.fdroid.fdroid/cache` and its subfolders. I encounter two problems

1. the folder path to be excluded is below the root path of the find command
   So this does not work (nothing excluded)

`find /data/data/*/cache -type f -not \( -name org.fdroid.fdroid  \) -print`

(for test purposes with `-print`)

2. When I reduce the root path to `/data/data` and try to work with `-path` and `-name` arguments such as

`find /data/data -path */cache/* -type f -not \( -name org.fdroid.fdroid  \) -print`

I get errors such as

> find: bad arg 'data/cache/backup_stage' and the `-not` argument is ignored.

This means `find` does not start at the root path defined in the command but at root of the phone `/` contrary to what I expect according to all descriptions I found.

Here [How to exclude a directory in find . command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command)

here [Remove only files in directory on linux NOT directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714900/remove-only-files-in-directory-on-linux-not-directories)
and in other places I didn't find a solution.

How can I accomplish this on my phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this I think.

```sh
find /data/data/*/cache -type f -not -path '/data/data/org.fdroid.fdroid/*' -mtime +3 -delete
```

Or

```sh
find /data/data/*/cache -type f -not -path '/data/data/org.fdroid.fdroid/cache/*' -mtime +3 -delete
```